# wcf service timer confusion

Tags: c#, wcf, timer, serial-port

I read some questions about wcf and timers but it does not help just jet.

I got the following scenario. I host a wcf-service inside a windows-service.

The wcf-service has an instance of SerialPort and connects to a device attached to the Port. Now i also have a timer that sends data to the device regularely.

when i connect to the wcf-service for the first time and start everything up, it works. sadly the moment i restart the client and do a call, i get an Exception. i then thought about my situation and decided, that i need some kind of singleton-wfc-service that under all circumstances gets only once instantiated so my pc never tries to open up the same SerialPort twice. I then lerned about [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]. Sadly i get "System.ServiceModel.FaultException" Exeptions as soon as i set InstanceContextMode.Single and i cant call something even 1 time now.

let me show you some code.

**First of, i got a ServiceContract**

```
public enum Side { Left, Right };

[ServiceContract]
public interface IColorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void setColor(Color color, Side side);
    [OperationContract]
    Color getColor(Side side);
    [OperationContract]
    void setEnable(bool enable, Side side);
    [OperationContract]
    bool getEnable(Side side);
    [OperationContract]
    void setColorCalculator(FullRangeFader colorCalculator, Side side);
}
```

**Here is my WCF-Service implementation**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ColorService : IColorService
{
    bool leftEnable = false;
    bool rightEnable = false;

    Color leftColor;
    Color rightColor;

    FullRangeFader leftColorCalculator = new FullRangeFader();
    FullRangeFader rightColorCalculator = new FullRangeFader();

    Timer timer = new Timer(16); // 100 Herz

    System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1;

    public ColorService() {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onTimer);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void onTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (leftEnable && leftColorCalculator != null)
            leftColor = leftColorCalculator.advance();
        if (rightEnable && rightColorCalculator != null)
            rightColor = rightColorCalculator.advance();
        sendData();
    }

    public void setColorCalculator(FullRangeFader colorCalculator, Side side) {
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                leftColorCalculator = colorCalculator;
                break;
            case Side.Right:
                rightColorCalculator = colorCalculator;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setEnable(bool enable, Side side) {
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                this.leftEnable = enable;
                break;
            case Side.Right:
                this.rightEnable = enable;
                break;
        }

        if (!rightEnable && !leftEnable)
            timer.Enabled = false;
        else
            timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public bool getEnable(Side side) {
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                return leftEnable;
            default:
                return rightEnable;
        }
    }

    public Color getColor(Side side)
    {
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                return leftColor;
            default:
                return rightColor;
        }
    }

    public void setColor(Color color, Side side)
    {
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                leftColor = color;
                break;
            default:
                rightColor = color;
                break;
        }
        sendData();
    }

    private void initSerialPort() {
        if (serialPort1 == null) { 
            serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
            serialPort1.Open();
        }
    }

    private void sendData()
    {
        initSerialPort();

        byte[] buf = { leftColor.R, leftColor.G, leftColor.B, rightColor.R, rightColor.G, rightColor.B };
        serialPort1.Write(buf, 0, 6);

        serialPort1.Close();
    }
}
```

**Finally there is my DataContract-Class, i want to create FullRangeFader Objects in my Client. As you can see i planned to make a father-class called ColorCalculator, so i can pass different Classes to my Service, for different calculations. But i have not understood, how to do that kind of stuff jet.**

```
[DataContract] 
public class FullRangeFader //: ColorCalculator
    {
        enum State
        {
            Start, RG, G, GB, B, BR, R
        }

        State state = State.Start;

        Color color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

        public Color advance() // override
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                // doing fancy calculations
            }
            return color;
        }
    }
```

Finally within my client i may use the wcf-service like:

```
        ServiceReference.ColorServiceClient client = new ServiceReference.ColorServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IColorService");

        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        client.setColor(colorDialog1.Color, Side.Left);

        client.setColorCalculator(new FullRangeFader(), Side.Left);
        client.setEnable(true, Side.Left);
```

This is where i get my error. I hope for some help... this is the first thing i not only do with wcf but with c# in general. thanks.

Stacktrace of the error:

bei System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   bei ClassLibrary.ColorService.sendData() in C:\Users\jonas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LED\ClassLibrary\ColorService.cs:Zeile 118.
   bei ClassLibrary.ColorService.setColor(Color color, Side side) in C:\Users\jonas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LED\ClassLibrary\ColorService.cs:Zeile 102.
   bei SyncInvokesetColor(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Comment: what IS the error? Did you check the event viewer? did you enable trace logging in the config file?

Comment: did you try using `lock` in order to synchronize access to the serial port? (`lock(lockObj){initSerialPort(); serialPort1.Write(...);serialPort1.Close()}`)?

Comment: i dont see anything inside the event viewer. the type of the exception is "System.ServiceModel.FaultException". I activated the error details and i now get the message: "Der Anschluss ist geschlossen." That translates to "The Connection is closed". I think this is related to the SerialPort... I included the Stacktrace.

Comment: oh crist. i just found the error! i am a dump person! Its a logical error:
after i send some data, i then close the port. But i do not reopen it.

Comment: wow it works really nice, thank you for pointing me to the trace logging. can i mark that somehow?

Comment: It would be better to post the solution to your problem as an answer and mark it as the solutuion.